# Can't redirect command output to file

Tags: bash, output, output-redirect

I've been writing a bash script to install PBIS Open when I execute the following command `domainjoin-cli join $domain $join_account $password` I can see the output on the terminal. However, if I try to capture the terminal output and save the output to a file, the file is empty.

I've tried adding  `<cmd> > output.txt`

I've tried using

`script output.txt
<cmd>
exit`

I've searched for a day now but I can't seem to find a working solution.

Comment: What is exactly the command that doesn't work?

Comment: `domainjoin-cli join $domain $join_account $password`

Comment: by adding `2>&1` you are only redirecting stderr to stdout. add further a `> outfile`, or to make it simple, do it like LeBarton

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two types of output stream `stdout` and `stderr`. It is probably coming out on the stderr stream. The `>` by itself will only capture the `stdout`.

Try executing with

```
<cmd> &> filename
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working! I tried more than the two things I added in the question, and I thought I tried everything. Apparently, I didn't.

Comment: The question is then: why the run program outputs in the stderr instead of the stdin